# Best way to display a game score on iPhone with cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking to persistently display a game score in an iPhone app using cocos2d.  Going off the code that cocos2d shows the FPS the app is running at:

```
-(void) showFPS
{
    frames++;
    accumDt += dt;

    if ( accumDt > 0.1)  {
        frameRate = frames/accumDt;
        frames = 0;
        accumDt = 0;
    }

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",frameRate];
    [FPSLabel setString:str];
    [FPSLabel draw];
}
```

I can get the score to display properly, but it flickers, even though the app is running at faster that 60 FPS...  Any ideas?

Comment: One thing about this code that you showed, don't message FPSLabel with draw. Instead, use [FPSLabel setNeedsDisplay:YES] after you update it. This should cancel your flicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using LabelAtlas instead. It is faster (it consumes much less CPU).
See the AtlasDemo that comes with the cocos2d distribution to see how to use it.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who might be interested, I ended up using a cocos2d Label as so:

```
scoreLabel = [Label labelWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score] dimensions: CGSizeMake(180, 20) alignment: UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Arial" fontSize: 20];
[scoreLabel setPosition: cpv(100,100)];
[self add: scoreLabel];
```

Hopefully this can help someone else.

Comment: As of Cocos2d 0.8, you should use a BitmapFontAtlas, as it is way faster for something that's updated frequently on screen.